# How to capture Referral parameters from m.me links inside MS Chatbot?

Tags: node.js, parameter-passing, botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I have integrated a survey chatbot with my Facebook page. I want to send personalised [m.me](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links/) links to my users via email. These links contain a unique referral parameter that can identify a user's transaction. So when a user clicks the m.me link I want my chatbot to capture this parameter from the link and send a proactive personalised welcome message to the user. So far I've unsuccessfully tried using a middleware to capture payloads from incoming requests.

```
const restify = require('restify');
let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 80, function () {
console.log(`\n${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
console.log(`\nTo talk to your bot, open simplePrompts.bot file in the Emulator`);});
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
    // Route to main dialog.
    await myBot.onTurn(context);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe for messaging_referrals in your webhook. Then you would get the referral parameter as well. You can read how to set it up and how the event will be provided from the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_referrals/